# Removing specific items from list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi im trying to figure out a way I can remove specific items from my list.

This is how I am currently drawing cards in my game:

```
public IEnumerator StartGame()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        GameObject card = Instantiate(deck[deck.Count - 1], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        card.transform.SetParent(hand.transform, false);
        hand.Add(deck[deck.Count - 1]);
        deck.RemoveAt(deck.Count - 1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
    turnState = State.DrawPhase;
}
```

If possible I would like someway I could remove the gameobject from my "hand" list at the same time i remove it in the game. (If there is a better way to go about this I would like to know).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are looking for a method that removes an object from the list at the same time as destroying it. So you need an Extension class like the one below.

```cs
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static void DestroyAt(this List<GameObject> myList, int index)
    {
        GameObject.Destroy(myList[index]); // destroy object
        myList.RemoveAt(index); // remove it from list
    }
}
```

```cs
public void Start() => hand.DestroyAt(1); // for e.g
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was more looking for a way to link the Instantiated object with its list counterpart. So once the card has been drawn if i were to discard it, it would remove the discarded card from the list.

Comment: @CodingNewbie then you should consider using `Queue` for deck instead of `List`. `Dequeue` function will remove an item from `Queue` and return that item so you can add it to your **Hand** `List`